# mongoDB not installing my system I'm getting the following Error

Tags: mongodb

[image: Console Error]

mongoDB not installing my system im geting the following Error

Comment: Did you start the server before trying to connect to it? Otherwise, you've missed a step in the installation.

Answer (score 1):

You need to run `mongod.exe` to start an instance of MongoDB. Once that is up and running you can run the client `mongo.exe` to connect to your MongoDB instance.